# How to find the temperature scheduling for simulated annealing?

Tags: optimization, simulated-annealing

I have a combinatorial optimization problem that I try to solve using simulated annealing.

It is about finding the optimal configuration of N points on a grid. I have the operation swap (swap one point with another one) and move (move one point to a new coordinate on the grid).

I already implemented the simulated annealing algo and estimated the initial temperature.

Now I am wondering if there is a way to find a good temperature schedule. How should I start? So far I only found several schedulings, but it seems like I should use trial and error to find the best one for my problem.

Furthermore, I would like to know if it is ok to consider only one operation (move, swap) at once. Or should I apply several moves and/or swaps and then calculate the energy difference and accept or reject the new configuration. I think, if I make several moves/swaps at once, I will generate states that are far more rejected. Is this correct?

I still couldn't find any nice simulated annealing literature, so I would be happy for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error is all that I know of, alas.

Yes, normally we apply one move, compute the effect on energy, and decide whether to accept this move or not.

Answer (score 0):

I see no better way than to experiment with your problem, hoping that you can draw general conclusions about the behavior of annealing on it. Any problem-specific information you could have about the distribution of the local maxima can be useful.

You can try different starting temperatures and observe the number of trials it takes before the solution stops to improve. You can observe the spread of the values around that "steady state" solution, and possibly study a relation between the temperature and the spread.

Now if you can master this first step, restart observations with lower temperatures from this point, and so on. The goal is to minimize the total number of trials to reach a given accuracy.

---

Unless you have other degrees of freedom, combining several swaps and moves is a way to adjust the temperature. But you need a rule to decide which ones to apply at a given stage.